# Is there a way to print a formatted string from the log action in eclipse CDT breakpoint action?

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt, breakpoints

I am trying to display a formatted string directly from a breakpoint action in eclipse-cdt (when programming in C).

I have configured a conditional breakpoint and associated 2 actions to it :
- a log action (I have checked the "evaluate as expression" checkbox) 
- a resume action to prevent the debugger from actually stopping at that breakpoint

I haven't found any documentation on the expected log action expression syntax : I have tried a couple of variations  but I have only been able to display a single variable content. From these attempts I have found that it expects neither C statements such as printf("i = %d",i); nor gdb printf syntax.

I would have liked to print a string like "i = 12 and sum = 34".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Maybe_ `char buf[60]; sprintf(buf, "i = 12 and sum = 34",i,, sum); fputs(buf, stdout);`

Comment: I had tried a similar solution but it prints `char buf[60]; sprintf(buf, "i = 12 and sum = 34",i,, sum); fputs(buf, stdout);: evaluation failed.`

Comment: Two commas `i,, sum`?

Comment: Even with a single comma the error message is the same. Only printf seems to be accepted and without a semi colon at the end of the expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call printf like you would in regular code but don't put semicolon at the end. Works for me. Note that this will print text to your apps stdout and it will look like normal app text output.

Tested on:
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627